# ListView.onRemove animation vs childrenRect.height

Tags: qml, qt5, qt-quick, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I noticed strange behaviour in ListView childrenRect.height when I am removing elements from its model with ListView.onRemove animation. When I remove all elements except the last one, childrenRect.height property is wrong, but contentHeight property is ok. Removing ListView.onRemove animation results the problem disappears. Why childrenRect.height is wrong?

Using [this code](http://pastebin.com/23MkDa8S) You will see that after You remove all elements except the last one, You cannot click in some area.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
MouseArea
{
    id: container
    height: 400; width: 600
    Rectangle { id: point; visible: false; width: 6; height: 6; radius: 3; color: "black" }
    onPressed: { point.visible = true; point.x = mouse.x - 3; point.y = mouse.y - 3; }
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement { lorem: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem." }
        ListElement { lorem: "Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam." }
        ListElement { lorem: "Quisque semper justo at risus. Donec venenatis, turpis vel hendrerit interdum, dui ligula ultricies purus, sed posuere libero dui id orci." }
        ListElement { lorem: "Nam congue, pede vitae dapibus aliquet, elit magna vulputate arcu, vel tempus metus leo non est." }
    }
    ListView {
        id: messageListView
        model: listModel
        anchors.top: container.top; anchors.left: container.left; anchors.right: container.right
        height: childrenRect.height
        onCountChanged: console.log("count: " + count)
        onHeightChanged: console.log("height: " + height) // sometimes wrong
        onContentHeightChanged: console.log("contentHeight: " + contentHeight) // rather ok
        delegate: Item {
            id: messageItem
            anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.right: parent.right
            height: Math.max(50, messageText.height + 12)
            Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 1; opacity: 0.75; color: "green"; radius: 5 }
            Text {
                id: messageText
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter; anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.right: removeButton.left; anchors.margins: 10
                text: lorem
                color: "white"; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter; wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                font.pixelSize: 16; font.weight: Font.Bold
                style: Text.Outline; styleColor: "black"
                maximumLineCount: 6; elide: Text.ElideRight
            }
            Button {
                id: removeButton
                enabled: (index !== -1) && (messageItem.opacity === 1.0)
                anchors.right: parent.right; anchors.margins: 5
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter; implicitHeight: 40; implicitWidth: 40
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("remove: " + index);
                    listModel.remove(index);
                }
            }
            ListView.onRemove: SequentialAnimation {
                PropertyAction { target: messageItem; property: "ListView.delayRemove"; value: true }
                /// PROBLEM BEGIN
                NumberAnimation { target: messageItem; properties: "opacity"; from: 1.0; to: 0.0; duration: 500 }
                /// PROBLEM END
                PropertyAction { target: messageItem; property: "ListView.delayRemove"; value: false }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `ListView.childrenRect` may be dynamically changed by itself. For example, try to drag the view when your example code launched. As all four delegates disappeared from the top of the view, `childrenRect.height` increased (even if you comment out the `NumberAnimation`). 
That means `ListView` uses it's `childrenRect` to something internally, like drag animation, thus this property is not reliable to ListView users.

Use `contentHeight` instead of `childrenRect.height` so you can always obtain the correct value . Or use `contentItem.childrenRect.height` that does the same thing according to [Flickable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#contentHeight-prop).